WordPress Flatsome custom UX Builder element, display children elements
I'm struggling with kind of the same problem.. I just can't get child elements to display on the website. In the UX builder, I can add children elements and they display, when when I exit the UX builder, the children elements simply don't display.


As you can see in the provided images, they won't appear in normal view. Here is my code:
flatsome-elements.php (main file):
...
public function cards_shortcode($atts) {
        $atts = shortcode_atts([
            'href' => 'javascript:void();',
            'background_color' => '#fff',
            'text_color' => '#000',
            'text' => 'Button',
            'letter_case' => '',
            'padding' => '16',
            'margin' => '5',
        ], $atts);

        ob_start();

        require(FLATSOME_ELEMENTS_PATH . 'public-html/cards.html');

        $output = ob_get_clean();

        return $output;
    }

    public function card_item_shortcode($atts) {
        $atts = shortcode_atts([
        ], $atts);

        ob_start();

        require(FLATSOME_ELEMENTS_PATH . 'public-html/cards-item.html');

        $output = ob_get_clean();

        return $output;
    }

    public function setup_ux_builder() {
        require_once FLATSOME_ELEMENTS_PATH . 'integrations/flatsome.php';
    }

integrations/flatsome.php:
... 
add_ux_builder_shortcode('flatsome_cards', [
    'name' => __('Custom Cards', 'fee'),
    'category' => __('BliSynlig AS'),
    'type' => 'container',
    'allow' => array( 'flatsome_card_item' ),
]);

add_ux_builder_shortcode('flatsome_card_item', [
    'name' => __('Custom Card Item', 'fee'),
    'category' => __('BliSynlig AS'),
    'require' => array( 'flatsome_cards' ),
    'wrap' => false,
    'hidden' => true,
]);

public-html/cards.html:
<div class="cards"><div id="buttons"></div><div id="container"><content></content></div></div>   

public-html/cards-item.html:
<div class="cards-item">element</div> 

I've tried requiring the do_shortcode() function which seems to switch out the <content><content/> tag with children elements, but that doesn't solve the issue.
If anyone has done this before, I would appriciate any guidance :)
